# How to perform touch gestures to other apps in android

Tags: android, accessibilityservice, android-touch-event

I have an android application required to perform touch gestures in entire android device and not just my own application I found these solutions:

1. Using adb Commands
2. ROOTing Android Device
3. Accessibility Service in Android 7.0 or higher

Is there any other solution?